Adding new files in Rails engine's lookup context
I am making a rails engine which has a themes folder , in app/apps/themes . When you install the gem in a host application , the user should have the ability to add a new theme depending on their choice. But how should the theme and its views access the data present in the tables already created by the engine.
Also how will the engine's configuration about the new theme and using it ?
For now in the engine , in my controller I have prepended the view paths of some dummy themes , like this
prepend_view_path MyEngine::Engine.root.join("app/apps/themes/#{session[:current_theme]}/views")

The current_theme in session storage stores the picked theme, but in the host application , how will I make it know about the new theme thats's been added...

access the data present in the tables - what tables? do you mean models? you have access to everything in any view, but you should use instance or local variables in your views and assign those variables from controllers. configuration about the new theme - you can make an initializer and lookup if user created a theme directory: Rails.root.join("app/themes").children

you can make an initializer and lookup if user created a theme directory: Rails.root.join("app/themes").children , I can write a script in intializers to detect any themes present in app/apps/themes and precompile its assets ???

you have access to the filesystem so yes.
